# How to generate google font kit id (download url)?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, google-webfonts

I wish I could use download endpoint (`https://www.google.com/fonts/download?kit=`)

"Open Sans" => `3hvsV99qyKCBS55e5pvb3ltkqrIMaAZWyLYEoB48lSQ`

"Open Sans" and "Roboto" => `3hvsV99qyKCBS55e5pvb3oFhj6aVr1SiN3yU3qUgn_eglnMp3_3A8V8Ai8YosRtX`

Looks like encoded/serialized data (baseX or something).

How is this id generated?

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/google/fonts/ ?

Comment: Yes. I know about this repo but i hope i can just use google fonts api (does not provide license info. sad. still can parse "specimen" page) and download endpoint (archive with license file and nice filenames). I am using google app engine, so api and endproint preferred way.